# 3D print toolbox is missing from Add Ons

Tags: add-on, customization, 3d-printing

I'm new to 3D printing and I would like to use blender to generate some simple models. I've used it before, but I am still a novice. The first thing every instruction set mentions when trying to make 3D printable models is to make sure that the 3D Print Toolbox is installed. I've gone to Edit->Preferences->Add Ons and searched for this, but nothing with that name appears. I have heard that it is supposed to be included with Blender 3+ and I'm running version 3.4.1 on Ubuntu Mate 22.04.

Comment: I saw already asked this question by Ubuntu user ... I can't find it to mark as duplicate ... same as @GordonBrinkmann on Windows ... my Mac version includes the addon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Ubuntu, but in Windows it is there. How exactly are you searching for it? It is found under *Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox*. If you are entering "3d" in the search field for example it should appear. Also with "3d-print", but if you search for "3d print" without hyphen as you wrote it in your question, it will not show up.

[image: search for 3d-print]